# sapply and lapply for changing integer to factor

Tags: r, lapply

I have a column which is integer and I would like to make it factor.
This is the code that I use.

```
vec_integer <- sapply(train, is.integer)
train[] <- lapply(train[,vec_integer==TRUE], as.factor)
```

and this is the error:

> cannot allocate vector of size 423 Kb
>   Error during wrapup: cannot allocate vector of size 423 Kb

Can Someone help me understanding why what I try is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue could be related to unequal sizes on lhs and rhs

```
train[vec_integer] <- lapply(train[vec_integer], factor)
```

---

We can also do this with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
train %>%
      mutate_if(is.integer, factor)
```

#### data

```
train <- structure(list(DATE = structure(c(17371, 17371, 17371, 17372, 
17372, 17372, 17373, 17373, 17373, 17374, 17374, 17374, 17375, 
17375, 17375, 17376, 17376, 17376), class = "Date"), VALUE = c(2L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 
1L), YEAR = c(2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2003L, 
2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L)), .Names = c("DATE", "VALUE", "YEAR"), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), class = "data.frame")
```